# Which Generic is suitable to retrieve a Custom DataType in the reverse order from how they were entered?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, collections

I use Asp.net 4 and C#, Linq and EF 4.

I need to retrieve in the **reverse order how how they were entered** instances for a Custom DataType (in my case CmsCategory).

The collection will contain maximum 10 items.

**Which `System.Collections.Generic` fits in this situation?**

Comment: Order reversing for a trivial length colleciton is pretty much orthogonal to the type of collection. The question makes little sense.

Comment: TomTom it is a legitimate  question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the generic Stack:

```cs
var stack = new Stack<int>();
stack.Push(1);
stack.Push(2);
stack.Push(3);
stack.Pop(); // 3
stack.Pop(); // 2
stack.Pop(); // 1
```

Or just use a simple List and then call Reverse():

```cs
var list = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};
list.Reverse(); // {3, 2, 1}
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Rogers the list.Reverse() was the solution I was looking for.